# Maven sonar scan failing for SonarQube 7.7 with sonar-groovy 1.6-RC1

Tags: groovy, build, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am getting below error with sonar maven plugin 3.6.0.1398 for SonarQube 7.7 with sonar-groovy 1.6-RC1, is there a patch for this issue?

```
Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1398:sonar (default-cli) 
on project xxxxx: org.sonar.plugins.groovy.codenarc.CodeNarcSensor has unsatisfied dependency 
'class org.sonar.plugins.groovy.foundation.GroovyFileSystem' for constructor 
'public org.sonar.plugins.groovy.codenarc.CodeNarcSensor(org.sonar.api.profiles.RulesProfile,
org.sonar.plugins.groovy.foundation.GroovyFileSystem)' from org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer@6c27e700:113
<[Immutable]:org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer@168142da:336
<[Immutable]:org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer@69e8b711:54<
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated SonarQube recently?
sonar-groovy 1.6-RC1 is not compatible with Sonar 7.7.

Try to update the plugin to 1.6 version (it has support for SonarQube 6.7-7.9) and restart SonarQube:
https://github.com/Inform-Software/sonar-groovy/releases